# Confusions related to Redshift about dataset (Structured, Unstructured, Semi-structured) and format to be used

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-emr

1. Can anyone explain me clearly about what kind of data Redshift can handle(like structured, unstructured , or in any formats)?
2. **How to copy `Cloudfront logs` into Amazon Redshift even the log is in unstructured data without going to Amazon EMR?**
3. **How to find `Database size` which is created in Amazon Redshift?

Please someone explain me clearly about all the three questions which i have mentioned it above...**It will be better if you explain me with some example or sample code or any source** `it will be very helpful for my project`

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Redshift provides a **standard SQL interface** (based on PostgreSQL). Therefore, it is best suited for structured data that is stored in Tables, Rows and Columns.

It is also possible to store **JSON records** within a field and access them via [JSON functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html).

To load data into Amazon Redshift, it needs to be in a delimited file format, such as comma delimited, tab delimited, fixed-length fields or JSON format. Any data that is not in a suitable format will need to be **pre-processed and converted to a suitable format**. This could be done with tools such as [Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/) (Presto) or [Amazon EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/) (Hadoop).

Amazon CloudFront logs are in Tab-Delimited format and can be loaded directly into Amazon Redshift. For an example, see: [Analyzing S3 and CloudFront Access Logs with AWS Redshift](http://techblog.thescore.com/2014/05/14/analyzing-s3-and-cloudfront-access-logs-with-redshift/)

Information about disk space consumed by tables can be obtained via the [`SVV_DISKUSAGE`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_DISKUSAGE.html) system view.

Comment: CloudFront logs are supposed to be fixed field tab delimited. If you don't want all the fields you could COPY them into a temp table and then move/transform the fields you want to a main table. By managing the max_errors of the COPY command you can skip header rows, etc.(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html#LogFileFormat)

Comment: Ah! You're right, @systemjack. I've updated my answer accordingly. Thank you!